# SQL CONTAINS doesn't work

Tags: php, sql

Hy, i'm try to execute this code

```
public function CardsTextSearch($text){

    $hashed_text = md5($text);
    echo "HASHED ".$text." IN ".$hashed_text."<br>";
    $result = array();
    $sql = "SELECT cardID,cardName FROM Cards WHERE CONTAINS(hashedCardName, '$hashed_text')";

    if ($sth = $this->DBH->query($sql) ){
        //echo "PREPARED <br>";
        //$sth->execute(array($hashed_text));
        echo "EXECUTED: ";
        var_dump($sth);
        echo "<br>";
        $row = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        var_dump($row);
        echo "<br>ROW: ".$row."<hr>";


    }else{
        echo "ERRORE<br>";
        print_r($this->DBH->errorInfo());
    }
    var_dump($result);
    echo "RESULT<hr>";
    return $result;

}
```

Leaving aside the because of a search on the encrypted string (simply because the field  cardName is varchar (150), so do not indexable), can you tell me if there is any error in the code, because the query does not work, and the output is generated is the following:

> HASHED Bad Moon IN 9e326d217f275a19ba1df92cb64be771
>
> EXECUTED: Object(PDOStatement)#5 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(100) "SELECT cardID,cardName FROM Cards WHERE CONTAINS(hashedCardName, '9e326d217f275a19ba1df92cb64be771')" } 
>   array(0) { } 
>   ROW: Array

I'm sure that there's an existing value of hashedCardName='9e326d217f275a19ba1df92cb64be771' in the DB, less sure that the column hashedCardName has been indexed.
It may be that the column has not been indexed or have I done something wrong in the code?

P.S. 
I also try with $stmt = $this->DBH-> prepare() and execute() as u can see in some comment that i had left.

Answer (score 0):

`Contains` doesn't work. Try `Like` or `Instr`:

```
SELECT * FROM Cards 
WHERE hashCardName like '$hashed_text';

SELECT * FROM Cards
WHERE INSTR(hashCardName, '$hashed_text');
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66f81/7)

Comment: Thanks!
I know i can use like, but in big DB Contains is more perormant than like, that must search in all rows of the table instead...and INSTR it seem the same. I didn't know that CONTAINS doesn't work. Did you know why?

Comment: If you know that the hash is EXACTLY `9e326d217f275a19ba1df92cb64be771`, why not compare it directly `hashCardName = '$hashed_text'` and add an index on `hashCardName` - this will be most performant of all :)

Comment: In that way yes...i also think that a text search based on the hash is not useful, because the hash is always a 32char string and it's different for all words...so if i type a seacrh of "hello" can't find the complete string "Hello World".